# Multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

I've read multiple inheritance from a book known as "C++ Primer" but I've only received a header file for the example written in the book which makes it little difficult for me to understand without source.cpp. So, my question is, what is an `Endangered` class and how do i define the member functions `highlight`, `cuddle`, `onExhibit` etc?

This header file can also be downloaded from [here](http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=0201721481).

```
// Multiple Inheritance.h

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Endangered {
public:
    virtual ~Endangered();
    virtual std::ostream& print(std::ostream&) const;
    virtual void highlight() const;
    // ...
};

class ZooAnimal;
extern std::ostream&
operator<<(std::ostream&, const ZooAnimal&);

class ZooAnimal {
public:
    ZooAnimal();
    ZooAnimal(std::string animal, bool exhibit,
              std::string family): nm(animal), 
                                   exhibit_stat(exhibit), 
                                   fam_name(family) { } 
    virtual ~ZooAnimal();

    virtual std::ostream& print(std::ostream&) const;
    virtual int population() const;

    // accessors
    std::string name() const { return nm; }
    std::string family_name() const { return fam_name; }
    bool onExhibit() const { return exhibit_stat; }
    // ...
protected:
    std::string nm;
    bool        exhibit_stat;
    std::string fam_name;
    // ...
private:
};

class Bear : public ZooAnimal {
enum DanceType { two_left_feet, macarena, fandango, waltz };
public:
    Bear();
    Bear(std::string name, bool onExhibit=true, 
         std::string family = "Bear"):
                         ZooAnimal(name, onExhibit, family),
                         ival(0), dancetype(two_left_feet) { }

    virtual std::ostream &print(std::ostream&) const;
    virtual int toes() const;
    int mumble(int);
    void dance(DanceType) const;

    virtual ~Bear();
private:
    int         ival;
    DanceType   dancetype;
};

class Panda : public Bear, public Endangered {
public:
    Panda();
    Panda(std::string name, bool onExhibit=true);
    virtual ~Panda();
    virtual std::ostream& print(std::ostream&) const;
    void highlight();
    virtual int toes();
    virtual void cuddle();
// ...
};

Panda::Panda(std::string name, bool onExhibit)
      : Bear(name, onExhibit, "Panda") { }

inline
std::ostream& Panda::print(std::ostream &os) const
{
    Bear::print(os);          // print the Bear part
    Endangered::print(os);    // print the Endangered part
    return os;
}

class PolarBear : public Bear { /* . . . */ };
```

Comment: Without reading that book, I think the point of the example is not get hang up on the implementation details of highlight() and cuddle() in the base class Endangered. Does it really matter for you to understand how a panda cuddle or dance?

The reason I comment is because you were looking for source.cpp which I think you are heading in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 0):

Just have functions with the same name, return type, argument number, const-ness, and argument types (known collectively as the *function signature*) in your class that you're deriving.

For instance,

```
// Me.h

class Me : public Endangered, public ZooAnimal {
    // notice that these don't have virtual before them
    std::ostream& print(std::ostream&) const;
    void highlight() const;
    std::ostream& print(std::ostream&) const;
    int population() const;

    /* etc */
};

// Me.cpp

std::ostream& Me::print(std::ostream& stream) const { /* stuff */; return stream; }

void Me::highlight() const { /* stuff */ }

/* etc */
```

Note that the destructors for those classes must be defined for each class, not for derived classes. So you'd need

```
ZooAnimal::~ZooAnimal() {
    /* stuff */
}
```

not `Me::~Me` (although you'd need that too if `Me` had one).

somewhere.